# Use SSL self-signed certificate to connect to ScyllaDB (cassandra) node on Windows?

Tags: python, ssl, cassandra, scylla, datastax-python-driver

I've generated a self-signed cert using [this scylla tutorial](https://docs.scylladb.com/stable/operating-scylla/security/generate-certificate.html). Started a scylladb node, everything's fine and dandy.

Now it's time to connect clients. Here's the script:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

ssl_options = dict(
    ca_certs='db.crt',
    cert_reqs=False,
    ssl_version=None,
    keyfile=None,
    certfile=None
)

cluster = Cluster(
    ['<my_ip>'], port=9142,
    ssl_options=ssl_options
)
cluster.connect()
```

The `db.crt` file is the PEM format certificate for the private key signed by the CA.

On `Ubuntu 22.04` it works as expected. On windows 10 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...", line 27, in <module>
    cluster.connect()
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 1734, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 1770, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 1757, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3573, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3618, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'<my_ip>': OSError(None, "Tried connecting to [('<my_ip>', 9142)]. Last error: timed out")})
```

I thought that this is a connectivity problem, but once I get rid of `ssl_options`, it connects to the server successfully, but treats the incoming bytes wrongly, ending up with such error:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'<my_ip>': ProtocolError('This version of the driver does not support protocol version 21')})
```

So I'm able to reach the server. It seems like windows is treating the certificate the wrong way or something. What can it be?

*P.S.* There is also a deprecation warning: `DeprecationWarning: Using ssl_options without ssl_context is deprecated and will result in an error in the next major release. Please use ssl_context to prepare for that release.`.

I've looked at the [cqlshlib implementation](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/cqlshmain.py), and it seems like it's still using the "deprecated" method of handling the `ssl`.

How can one use `SSLContext` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking all over the internet and finally found this: https://blog.amussey.com/post/64036730812/cassandra-2-0-client-server-ssl-with-datastax-python